# How to pass a table name as an argument in a saved procedure in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-apex

General question: How do I pass a table name as a parameter to a procedure in Oracle APEX?  For example, suppose I want to run the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT SOME_VALUE FROM A_TABLE
```

What is the simplest, most dumbed down code to do this?  I'm a SQL beginner, and have basically only glanced at PL/SQL.

In more detail, I have the following procedure from the Advanced Tutorials to allow me to download a BLOB from a custom table, but the bit of code which specifies the table to download from is hard coded.  I'd rather not have to make a new procedure for each table I want to store BLOBs in.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE download_my_file(p_file in number) AS
        v_mime  VARCHAR2(48);
        v_length  NUMBER;
        v_file_name VARCHAR2(2000);
        Lob_loc  BLOB;
BEGIN
        SELECT MIME_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT, name,DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_content)
                INTO v_mime,lob_loc,v_file_name,v_length
                FROM oehr_file_subject
                WHERE id = p_file;
              --
              -- set up HTTP header
              --
                    -- use an NVL around the mime type and 
                    -- if it is a null set it to application/octect
                    -- application/octect may launch a download window from windows
                    owa_util.mime_header( nvl(v_mime,'application/octet'), FALSE );

                -- set the size so the browser knows how much to download
                htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_length);
                -- the filename will be used by the browser if the users does a save as
                htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="'||replace(replace(substr(v_file_name,instr(v_file_name,'/')+1),chr(10),null),chr(13),null)|| '"');
                -- close the headers            
                owa_util.http_header_close;
                -- download the BLOB
                wpg_docload.download_file( Lob_loc );
end download_my_file;
```

Thanks!

Comment: lots of comments in the solution code to explain what stuff does would be super helpful.

Comment: If I were you I'd turn this around the other way - put the common code (all the htp calls, etc.) in a single routine, and have a separate "download_my_file" procedure for each table called as appropriate, all of which query their different tables, then call the common procedure to do the htp stuff. No dynamic SQL needed, no SQL injection vulnerability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL with execute immediate, it accepts queries as parameter. So, in your dumbed down example it would be:

> execute immediate 'select acolumn from '||p_tablename using l_column;

Detailed info and examples here :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Comment: But your final code should also include assertions to help secure from SQL injection http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php